# Fill DataGridView from checkedListBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a checkedListBox1 and i want to convert all it's items to a DataGridView
i have the following code

```
 string[] ar = new string[60];
        for (int j = 0; j < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; j++)
        {
            ar[j] = checkedListBox1.Items[j].ToString();
        }
        dataGridView2.DataSource = ar;
```

but the dataGridView2 is filled with the **length** of the item instead of the item itself, can any one help?

Comment: Have you tried to use a `DataTable` instead of an array?

Comment: yes, the same result still appears

Comment: Using a string array as a data source will not work. You will have to use a DataTable or a List.

Answer (score 0):

These code blocks may give an idea (all is worked for me). CheckedListBox items returns a collection. It is coming from `IList` interface so if we use a List item as datasource for datagridview solves the problem. I used generic`List` as an additional class of `Sample`. When we use string array datagridview shows each items length. In here overried `ToString` returns original value.

```
class Sample
{
   public string Value { get; set; }

   public override string ToString()
   {
       return Value;
   }
}
```

In form class:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  CheckedListBox.ObjectCollection col = chk.Items;
  List<Sample> list = new List<Sample>();
  foreach (var item in col)
  {
      list.Add(new Sample { Value = item.ToString() });
  }

  dgw.DataSource = list;

 }
```

Comment: It is working for every item in checkedlistbox. If you want to add selected items, use `chk.SelectedItems` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This simple `DataTable` code appears to work...

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
for (int j = 0; j < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; j++) {
  dt.Rows.Add(checkedListBox1.Items[j].ToString());
}
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because DataGridView looks for properties of containing objects. For string there is just one property - length. So, you need a wrapper for a string like this.

```
string[] ar = new string[60];
for (int j = 0; j < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; j++)
{
    ar[j] = checkedListBox1.Items[j].ToString();
}
dataGridView1.DataSource = ar.Select(x => new { Value = x }).ToList();
```